# How to pass commands and options to PHP script in CLI (e.g. php file.php mycommand -d "my option")

Tags: php

I'm aware I can use getopt and argv in my PHP script, but I don't know how to do something like the following:

```
php file.php mycommand -d "my option"
```

I've tried to use getopt with this but I guess the mycommand upsets it:

```
var_dump(getopt('d:')); // empty array
```

Currently I use $argv to get the command but using this with -x options means I need to do some processing to extract the options. I'm hoping there is a proper way to do so:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(27) "file.php"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "mycommand"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "-d"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "my option"
}
```

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the space between option and value

**Command**

```
php 1.php -xmycommand -d"my option"
```

**PHP Code**

```
var_dump(getopt('x:d:'));
```

**Output**

```
array(2) {
  ["x"]=>
  string(9) "mycommand"
  ["d"]=>
  string(9) "my option"
}
```

Comment: Hi. Doesn't appear to work. Only populates the getopt array when I remove the mycommand. Also, the space appears to make no difference then either.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but not really what I was looking for. I don't really want the command to require the option prefix. Maybe I can look inside packages like Phinx that allow `vendor/bin/phinx migrate -e development`, see how they do it. Cheers